# Rendering different views in one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, model-view-controller, view

I want to have 2 kinds of views for the same posts in my rails application. For instance - in one where a logged in user can update and edit the post, and in the other any user can just view it and comment on it or select it.

How should I go about this? Do I need a separate class? I know I need a separate view for each, but how about the model and the controller?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

***1.case:*** your views are going to have similar content, but only the signed in users will have extra options like editing.

You should use a partial view and in your main view you should write something like this:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'edit_form' %>
<% end %>
```

Remember, the name of the partial should always start with a underscore, so your partial in this case would be called `_edit_form.html.erb` or `_edit_form.html.haml`, depending on what you are using.

***2.case:*** depending on if the user is signed in or not, you want to render completely different views, then you should handle it in your controller:

```
def show
  if signed_in?
    render 'show_with_edit'
  else
    render 'show_without_edit`
  end
end
```

And your files would be named `show_with_edit.html.erb` and `show_without_edit.html.erb`

Also, if your view for a signed in user was called `show` then you could just do this:

```
def show
  render 'show_without_edit' unless signed_in?
end
```

***3.case:*** if you want to change basically EVERYTHING depending if the user is signed in or not, you could create some custom methods and call them inside your original action like this:

```
def show 
  if singed_in? 
    show_signed_in
  else
    show_not_signed_in
  end
end

private

def show_signed_in
   # declaring some instance variables to use in the view..
   render 'some_view'
end

def show_not_signed_in
   # declaring some other instance variables to use in the view..
   render 'some_other_view'
end
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, but no, this is not a partial. I want a completely different kind of view - it will look differently (I also don't want the same layout), and also some of the actions are very different. For instance the person writing the post can edit while the person reading the post can review the post - add stars, select it as a favorite etc.

Comment: Got it now - I did your second option. But I don't want it to be signed in vs not signed in - is there a way to redirect otherwise, say `posts/id` redirects to the blog posts a logged in user can edit, and `posts/blog/id` or `blog/id` is for any user, logged in or not, with a dif view and url

Comment: i updated my question with a third option, no need for redirects

Comment: Okay thanks, I just implemented it, but I'm getting a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in PostsController#show` message in my browser

Comment: is there anything in adition that I need to change other than the controller and the two `show` views?

Comment: I found that issue - I didn't delete the original `show` I had which is now supposed to be show_signed_in. However when I tried deleting it, I get a `template is missing` message in the browser. Do I need to change anything else other than the controller? The routes perhaps?

Comment: nope, the routes are going to stay the same. It's just going to 'render' different stuff, nothing else :)

Comment: if you are going to use it in one of your custom methods to be rendered, then obviously not. If you are going to create two completely new views, then yes :) I don't know what you have rendered so far nor what views you will be rendering from now on

Comment: Ah. I tried the third option, and created two new files `show_with_edit` and `show_with_star`, then I deleted `show`, but I'm getting `Template is missing

Missing template items/show, application/show` in the browser

Comment: perhaps the `private` should be deleted? it doesn't seem to find it

Comment: that didn't help.. also now I get it - it's for the signed_in option

Comment: how can I check to see whether/where I'm doing that? I just copied your code instead of the current `show` I had, and changed the file names to the new ones and started these 2 new show views

Comment: if your getting that same error, find where you are calling `render 'show'`

Comment: I found that I have a `format.html # show.html.erb` in the method, but now I changed it to show_with_edit and I still have the same issue

Comment: somewhere else or in the controller? here there is nothing else. yes, I'm getting the same error

Comment: if you post your code i would have better insight of the situation

Comment: Okay, good point - I just posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925620/error-template-is-missing-unable-to-have-2-show-views-for-the-same-posts

Comment: If someone is reading this: I think the problem of @LucyWeatherford was that rails automagically wants to render the view with the same name at the end of a controller action. So you have to put a return after your render call to end the action function without a second rendering.