# Error - Template is missing, unable to have 2 show views for the same posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller, view

This is a follow up question to: [Rendering different views in one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923664/two-separate-show-views-for-the-same-database-in-rails/15923870)

The error I am getting is:

```
Template is missing

Missing template items/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

It should be noted, that I copied the `show.html.erb` file to two files `show_with_edit.html.erb` and `show_with_star.erb`, and deleted `show.html.erb` to avoid duplicates.

My Code in `posts_controller.rb`

```
def show
  if signed_in?
    show_signed_in
  else
    show_not_signed_in
  end
end  

def show_signed_in
  #add methods here
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show_with_edit.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
  render 'show_with_edit'
end

def show_not_signed_in
  #add methods here
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show_with_star.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
  render 'show_with_star'
end
```

I am aware that for now the two different views are identical, I just put there different text for now. Once I have this nailed down I'll add to each view its own methods and content etc.

Comment: remove the `respond_to` block

Comment: removing the `respond_to` block would remove the json response as well, which is not necessarily what he wants.

Comment: True, i was just looking to post the correct answer but you were faster. I was talking to this user in the previous question and knew the needs. nice answer, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put render in the wrong places.

```
def show_signed_in
  #add methods here
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show_with_edit.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
  render 'show_with_edit'
end
```

should be

```
def show_signed_in
  #add methods here
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'show_with_edit' }
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end
```

Note the `render` that is moved to the format.html block.

The same applies for show_not_signed_in.

Answer (score 0):

please check your route.rb file is properly written , eg: consider following

```
  resources :posts
     collection 
       get :show_not_signed_in
       get :show_signed_in
    end
```

collection you write the method that is get or post